# Django: If equals count

Tags: django

I have multiple `ListViews` for a specific model. I have a page that should show the number of results per `ListView` and link to that ListView.

How do I count the number of items in that View?

dashboard.html

```
{% if status == 'Open' %}
    {{ jobs.count }}
{% endif %}
```

dashboard view:

```
Dashboard(ListView):
    model = Job
```

Open View:

```
class JobOpenList(ListView):

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Job.objects.filter(status='Open')
```

Closed View:

```
class JobClosedList(ListView):

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Job.objects.filter(status='Closed')
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not the way to think about things. You can't ask for the number of things in a completely separate view. Instead, you need to calculate them in the view you are currently using.

You can use aggregation to count the number of items in each state:

```
Job.objects.values('state').annotate(count=Count('state'))
```